# how to get same information of CLI in terminal?

Tags: command-line, system

as we all know that we will get some information like how many updates are available , login time etc while we login in CLI session of Ubuntu.

is there any way I can get them in the Gnome-terminal or any GUI based terminal. I want that information.

I want exactly as this in the GUI based teminals.
[image]

From answer provided by question at closed vote .

```
frank@FRANK-NATHE:~$ cat /etc/motd
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-28-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '13.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

frank@FRANK-NATHE:~$
```

The command cat /etc/motd just giving the release information but the above image showing huge information about the system. I want all of that information over my terminal.

Thank you

Comment: The accepted answer for above mentioned question also tells you how to get it **everytime**.